# how to make username unique only amongst active users

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to make sure that the username field is unique, but only amongst active users. If an user is inactive, then their username can be used to create a new account. Is this possible in django? I am using MySQL by the way.

I have read about a conditional unique constraint, but it only works on postgres.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#condition

Comment: This is also possible in MySQL since version 8.0 iirc.

Comment: I am thinking of switching dbs in the future, so I dont want the solution to be db specific. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your mysql db you can create an unique constraint on both columns, so that not the user is unique, but the combination between the value isActive and username.

use

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`user`, `isActive`);
```

so that you can have an active and inactive user name at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- Write custom User model in which you can check if the username is unique amongst active users (recommended)
- Dont allow usernames to end with `_inactive_<int>`. When a user is marked as inactive, append there username with `_inactive_<int>` where the integer is used if a username is already inactive and the same username is made inactive. To get the username, the `_inactive_<int>` is discarded